# WebResource.axd to ScriptResource.axd?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to convert couple of `webresource.axd` calls to `ScriptResource.axd` calls. But it was throwing some error to me.

Can I get some views on conversion?

Comment: Please add some details. Code examples? What is the error?

Comment: what to convert ? this are done by asp.net, do not mess up, and why to mess up ?